# What is the difference between django classonlymethod and python classmethod?

Tags: python, django

Why is there a need for Django to introduce the decorator `classonlymethod` ?
Why can't it reuse python `classmethod`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The best explanation is [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9c92924cd5d164701e2514e1c2d6574126bd7cc2/django/utils/decorators.py#L6) itself:

```
class classonlymethod(classmethod):
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is not None:
            raise AttributeError("This method is available only on the class, not on instances.")
        return super().__get__(instance, cls)
```

The difference is that a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) can be called on an instance, having the same effect as calling it on the class, but the `classonlymethod` can only be called on the class.

Comment: So, the only difference between `classonlymethod` and `staticmethod` is in its signature?

Comment: @redskins80 No, the difference is that you *cannot* use a `classonlymethod` in a class instance.

Comment: @ankush981 and madjar, but what is the purpose of this? What use case is this supposed to support?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Beats me. Maybe check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758483/how-is-djangos-classonlymethod-useful

Comment: @ankush981 "It is used internally ... to give a descriptive error message" Yes, I suppose it is better than the generic python error message, especially if you might be concerned that users would do it incorrectly a lot.