# How is Django's classonlymethod useful?

Tags: python, django

The source code is below:

```
class classonlymethod(classmethod):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is not None:
            raise AttributeError("This method is available only on the view class.")
        return super(classonlymethod, self).__get__(instance, owner)
```

Though I can see that classonlymethod can only be called on the class and not on an instance unlike classmethod of python, why do we need such a "restriction"?

Not much on the www regarding classonlymethod and any layman examples appreciated as always.

Comment: ... I can't think of a single one.

Comment: @dm3514 not really. I saw that but that is just source and doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate? The question is what is the purpose of this behavior. The linked answer does not provide answer to the this.

Answer (score 5):

It is used internally on class-based views' `as_view` to give a descriptive error message to people who try to call it on an instance.

I'm not sure who first decided it's mandatory.

Comment: There are other answers showing what this does - but this is the only answer I have seen that shows why. This is what I wanted to know. Thanks.